# How to make Admob interstitial show without delay?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have a simple game made in android sdk. When the user has level failed I want an interstitial to appear, more or less exactly at that moment. The problem is from the code I have, is a @5 seconds delay from the moment that interstitial function start until interstitial appear(checked in LogCat. Here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if (getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id).length() > 0) {
        // Create the interstitial
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id));

        // Create ad request.
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
    }
    //initialise banner ad
    this.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.BannerAd_unit_id);
    showBanner();

}

public void openAd() {
    if (getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id).length() > 0) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                }
                interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        interstitial.show();
                    }

                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to cache the interstitial before that function is called. That delay is really bad....
Thanks!

Comment: I think that is impossible, since the advertisers just count the views and the clicks, so you would need to produce a view which is possible never shown. This is why those scenarios are not supported. By the way hat do you have for a connection to the internet? Such a huge delay I would only expect on a weak mobile connection.

Comment: @rekire: my wifi. then how others does it?

Comment: **OR**

start loading your add when failed level is about to be met.. okay.. definitely you programmed how a failed scenario is met..
and this would not be a problem for a fast network.. it just depends..

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are attempting to load the ad and show it at the same time. Loading requires a network request which is slow. This is never going to give you the experience you are after.

Recommended practice is to call `interstitial.loadAd(adRequest)` at the start of your game or level. And then at the end of your level call

```
if (interstitial.isAdLoaded() {
    interstitial.show();
}
```

Comment: Is it a problem for developers? I mean that if we use interstitial.loadAd(adRequest) at the start of the activity, for admob can all impressions count as just 1? I am suspiciuos about this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. interstitial.loadAd(req) makes an ad request. You do not generate an impression until you call interstitial.show()