# AdMob Intersitial Ad remove delay

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I check other topic there on SOF, and looking for some new knowledge. How to remove delay for showing Admob intersitial ad on this code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

if (getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id).length() > 0) {
    // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id));

    // Create ad request.
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
}

//initialise banner ad
this.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.BannerAd_unit_id);
showBanner();
}

public void openAd() {
if (getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id).length() > 0)          {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
            interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    interstitial.show();
                }

            });

        }
    });
}
}
```

originaly posted here: [How to make Admob interstitial show without delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891000/how-to-make-admob-interstitial-show-without-delay/28444416#28444416)

I`m newbie and just learning programming, that`s why I`m asking for example on this code :)

Edit:
this is how openAd is called

```
public synchronized void GameOver() {
    if (lives_left > 0) {
        //success! - game passed - save score
        ScoreManager.save_localscore_simple(score_times[currentLevel], "" + currentLevel, false);

        if (Level_Buttons.length >= currentLevel + 1)
            ScoreManager.save_localscore_simple(unlocked, "unlock" + (currentLevel + 1));

        if (sound_success != 0 && !sound_muted)
            sp.play(sound_success, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

        //intersitial ad 
        ad_counter++;
        if (ad_counter >= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.ad_shows_every_X_gameovers)) {
            openAd();
            ad_counter = 0;
        } 


    } else {
        //game not passed
        if (sound_gameover != 0 && !sound_muted)
            sp.play(sound_gameover, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }


    //open interstitial ad
    ad_counter++;
    if (ad_counter >= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.ad_shows_every_X_gameovers)) {
        openAd();
        ad_counter = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will do what you ask. But it is **not** what you should do as it will annoy your users and probably get your Admob account banned.

What you should do is call `interstitial.loadAd()` early, probably in your `onCreate()`.

```
public void onCreate() {
    // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.InterstitialAd_unit_id));

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Create another ad request.
            final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
    // Create ad request.
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Then **at a natural break point in your app** (in GameOver), call 

`if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
}`

Once you have returned from showing the ad (in `AdListener.onAdClosed()` you can call `interstitial.loadAd()` and repeat.

Comment: Oh William, I was hope you will reply on my question, and you are here :) Thanks! But can you explain me a little bit, because I`m learning and I`m very confused. How must I change my code to working? I was trying all ways but everytime I got a errors.